# What is the set-builder notation for the Complement of $A = \{2,4,6,8,10\}$ with respect to $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,...\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I searched for a problem with the same case as mine, but couldn't find one.

now, i can easily  write that $$ \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x < 2\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x > 10 \} \enspace. $$

but this wouldn't include the natural numbers between the elements of $A$, like $\{3,5,7,9\}$

how do include them in my notation?

Comment: You could append $\cup\{1,3,5,7\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would just write
$$ \{1,3,5,7,9\} \cup \{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\ge 11\} $$
Combining them into a single set builder would be *possible* but be less readable:
$$ \{n\in\mathbb N\mid n=1 \lor n=3\lor n=5\lor n=7\lor n=9 \lor n\ge 11\} $$
In practice the *most* readable way to write down this set is probably just
$$ \mathbb N \setminus\{2,4,6,8,10\}$$
which I would prefer in almost all cases, **except** in the particular situation of doing homework exercises that aim at checking you have understood how complementation and set difference work.

Answer (score 0):

$\{ x \in \mathbb{N}|2<x \lor x >10 \lor x = 3 \lor x= 5 \lor x=7 \lor x=9 \}$

Or:

$\{ x \in \mathbb{N}|2<x \lor x >10 \lor \exists y \in \mathbb{N} : x = 2y+1 \}$

Answer (score 0):

Its set builder form : $$\{x:x\in \mathbb{N}\ \ but x≠2,x≠4,x≠6,x≠8,x≠10\}$$

Comment: @Axe, do you look any answer so far to get accepted for this question?